# Snowflake:ERROR: Found character '\u0086'' instead of field delimiter ','

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Trying to COPY Command to load file into Snowflake

Unable to figure out the issue

Error:

```
ERROR - 100065 (22000): 01975398-0686-457e-0000-029178372dae: Found character '\u009d' instead of field delimiter ','
      File '/STAGEDW/2020-10-01/report_2020_05_20200702114836.gz', line 292, character 90
      Row 288 starts at line 291, column "TRANSIENT_STAGE_TABLE"[2]
```

File Format is

```
{"TYPE":"CSV","RECORD_DELIMITER":"\n","FIELD_DELIMITER":",","FILE_EXTENSION":null,"SKIP_HEADER":1,"DATE_FORMAT":"AUTO","TIME_FORMAT":"AUTO","TIMESTAMP_FORMAT":"AUTO","BINARY_FORMAT":"HEX","ESCAPE":"NONE","ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD":"\\","TRIM_SPACE":true,"FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY":"\"","NULL_IF":[""],"COMPRESSION":"AUTO","ERROR_ON_COLUMN_COUNT_MISMATCH":true,"VALIDATE_UTF8":true,"SKIP_BLANK_LINES":false,"REPLACE_INVALID_CHARACTERS":false,"EMPTY_FIELD_AS_NULL":true,"SKIP_BYTE_ORDER_MARK":true,"ENCODING":"UTF8"}
```

[image]

> When I set  ENCODING = 'iso-8859-1' and FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY as NONE, Below is what it showed

[image]

Comment: Apart from the fact, as the error message states, that there is a unicode character, u009d, in the file that Snowflake can't handle - what problems are you having resolving this? Are you unable to edit file and are therefore looking for a way to get Snowflake to process it anyway?

Answer (score 1):

On observing error message it's seems failing for encoding issue, Could you please try include ENCODING = 'iso-8859-1' parameter in file format.

If possible please share the sample record I will give a try on this.

Comment: I cannot share in public , email me kauchy at gmail

Comment: Anything help to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

Remove  "FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY":""" , recreate the file format and run the copy statement again.